# What would be default sorting for users without sorting tabs?

Tags: support, questions, profile-page, sorting

Some users don't have sorting tabs (may be because of they have questions less than a page).

[image]

So, what would be default sorting for them? votes?, views? newest or recent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be newest, which sorts by question creation date. In your example, the question was edited 33 minutes ago, but actually was asked back on April 8th, before the other question asked April 28th.

As a side note, the sort buttons will show up once there are three or more items in the list.